# TFS 2013 Story Points burndown/trend chart

Tags: charts, report

I have a task to come up with a Story Point Burndown during the course of an iteration. Lets say, an Iteration starts with 19 story points, with each User Story containing 8, 5, 3, 2, 1 Story Points respectively. After a User Story is resolved or Closed, the chart should show a sharp drop in the trend line corresponding to its Story Point value. For example, if a 2 Story Points User Story is closed on the third day of the Iteration, the trend line should drop by 2 points...

This could be done using TFS Reports, I am thinking if it could be done more out of the box? that is, using TFS query Charts? Is that doable?

Comment: Don't forget to let MS know you want this in the box: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/4473980-add-story-point-burndown-to-dashboard-and-reports

Answer (score 0):

TFS query Charts support viewing a count of work items or a sum of values for select numeric fields, such as Remaining Work or Original Estimate. But it can't showing a sharp drop in the trend line corresponding to its Story Point value on TFS Web Access.

But you can create a [Excel PivotCharts](https://www.visualstudio.com/it-it/docs/report/excel/create-status-and-trend-excel-reports) like below to track trend chart:

[image]